# objective C - How to connect to a Time Server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

I my iPhone app, I am trying to connect to a Time Server (RFC 868) to sync my clock. I tried search for directions to do so, but only came across samples / tutorial connecting to HTTP Servers.

Does anybody know how can I connect to a Time Server at a specific port (port 37) and how to fetch the response?

Any pointers / suggestions in this direction is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could adapt the code from [this client](http://www.prismmodelchecker.org/qprover/casestudies/ntpclient_probity/ntpclient/ntpclient.c).